# Excel: How to use conditional formatting to highlight missing data?

Tags: excel

I'm wondering how to use conditional formatting in order to highlight specific cells in a column that return an error message in another column after applying a function to it.

eg) Column 1 has data 1 ... n
    Column 2 has data f(1) ... f(n); f(n) being a function that sometimes returns errors.

I want to color the cells in Column 1 that return the error in column 2. How would you do this? Thanks!

Comment: are you on Excel 2007 or newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `ISERROR()`.

Let's say that column 1 is A and column 2 is B.

Select cell A1 and then select the whole column. Cell A1 should be slightly less dark than the other cells (it's the active cell in the selected range). Once you have this, go to conditional formatting and under 'New rule' and 'Use a formula to determine which cells to highight', put the formula:

```
=ISERROR(B1)
```

Pick a formatting (e.g. Fill and yellow) and click OK. That should highlight the cells for which column B has errors.

Comment: @AlexLin You're welcome. You can mark my answer as accepted (by clicking on the tick outline once the countdown is over) to indicate that it solved your problem :)